# "Empty response received" on facebook application with correct SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, heroku

When trying to access my facebook application[1] I got the following error:

```
Error while loading page from Testapp
Empty response received.
```

My application is hosted by Heroku and has a static page[2], and I'm using Rails. When I try to connect with facebook, nothing is show on the log. When accessing the page from its URL, I got this on the log:

```
2012-04-29T04:07:16+00:00 heroku[router]: GET cold-fire-1208.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=0
```

I'm not using any namespace on my facebook application, and the SSL appears to be correctly configured, as you can check on my URL. Also it seems to pass on SSL security tests.

To create the app, I started it on facebook, choosed heroku and ruby, and then I got a sinatra application working. After that, I deleted the sinatra application and started a new rails application, configuring the database as pg.

Following is my heroku config --long

```
DATABASE_URL        => postgres://cantsee
FACEBOOK_APP_ID     => id
FACEBOOK_SECRET     => secret
GEM_PATH            => vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
LANG                => en_US.UTF-8
PATH                => vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:bin
RACK_ENV            => production
SHARED_DATABASE_URL => postgres://cantsee
```

[1] http://apps.facebook.com/testapp/

[2] https://cold-fire-1208.herokuapp.com/

**ANSWER:**

I was able to access my application through its ID, like https://apps.facebook.com/360273344020802/ instead of its name. Not sure why yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to access my application through its ID, like https://apps.facebook.com/360273344020802/ instead of its name. Not sure why yet.